# Javascript Errors in Browser capture event with jQuery Listener? Or Response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, listener

OK I'm not really sure how to phrase this question.  I want to return the string that drops in my developer console.

Lets say I intentionally want to have an error drop (my script does not freeze I'm using a Simulated Async Loop).

Example:

```
page.run = (function(){     
     var eP = $('#someElement').position(); 
     console.log(eP);
})();
```

Ok lets say we call that knowing that we have no element in the DOM with the id #someElement... besides all the other reasons this example by its self is rubish lets pretend it runs and does not lock up the script so the console would be dropping Errors like: "TypeError: $(...).position(...) is undefined" with the line number of the script going on and on and on... blah. But then wham at some point you load that element it is looking for and it starts returning your console.log(eP);

So Ok now my question....

How Could I hyjack the "TypeError: $(...).position(...) is undefined" and line number script ect when it happens and use it for my own means?

Answer (score 0):

It returns undefined error because parent object-$('#someElement') is null. 
Please check not null condition of parent object-$('#someElement') and call the method and print it in console.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

credit goes to James Michael Winters, facebook beat stackoverflow to it sorry :-(